# populate spinner with retrofit and moshi

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

i am beginner in android dev (both java or kotlin). I am trying to populate spinner from json with retrofit and moshi but I have no idea how to populate it into spinner. to be honest I dont know whether the return of Json data is correct or not, since Log.d() return is not detail as dump() laravel or php.

script in activity onCreate (Please read the comment of the script, i put debug result of `Log.d()` there):

```
val task = object : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response<List<ProductTypeResponse>>>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Response<List<ProductTypeResponse>> {

            val typeAPI = RestAPI()
            val callResponse = typeAPI.getNews()
            val response = callResponse.execute()

            return response

        }

        override fun onPostExecute(response: Response<List<ProductTypeResponse>>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val news = response.body()
                Log.d("test:", news!![0].data.toString()) //  method 'java.lang.String com.example.mockie.tigaer.api.TypeDataResponse.toString()' on a null object reference
                Log.d("test:", news!!.size.toString()) // it says 67 but the data from the url is 63 array of json object
                Log.d("test:", news!![0].toString()) // com.example.mockie.tigaer.api.ProductTypeResponse@f17fd5e
            }
        }
```

RestApi.kt

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory

class RestAPI() {

private val tigaerApi: TigaerApi

init {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://app.tigaer.id/laravel/")
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

    tigaerApi = retrofit.create(TigaerApi::class.java)
}

fun getNews(): Call<List<ProductTypeResponse>> {
    return tigaerApi.getTop()
}
}
```

ApiModel.kt

```
package com.example.mockie.tigaer.api

class ProductTypeResponse(val data: TypeDataResponse)

class TypeDataResponse(
    val children: List<ProductTypeChildrenResponse>
 )

 class ProductTypeChildrenResponse(val data: ProductTypeDataResponse)

 class ProductTypeDataResponse(
    val productType: String,
    val readable: String
 )
```

TigaerApi.kt

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface  TigaerApi {
@GET("api/type")
fun getTop(): Call<List<ProductTypeResponse>>
}
```

return Json: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ce90c41b859218e746e41d64eddb4c30

so my questions are :

1. is there any function to debug object/array as detail as in laravel ?
2. how to populate my json return data into spinner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code for same, I modified and integrate in your code only:

**"MainActivity.kt" class:**

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)

    val task = object : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response<List<ProductTypeDataResponse>>>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Response<List<ProductTypeDataResponse>> {

            val typeAPI = RestAPI()
            val callResponse = typeAPI.getNews()
            val response = callResponse.execute()

            return response

        }

        override fun onPostExecute(response: Response<List<ProductTypeDataResponse>>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val news: List<ProductTypeDataResponse>? = response.body()

                var adapter: SpinnerAdapter = SpinnerAdapter(this@MainActivity, news!!);

                spinner.adapter=adapter


               }
        }
    }.execute()
}
}
```

**Now Layout "activity_main":**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ankitpatidar.checkkotlin.MainActivity">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"></Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Now Spinner Adapter as "SpinnerAdapter":**

```
 class SpinnerAdapter internal constructor(internal var context: Context, internal var list: List<ProductTypeDataResponse>) : BaseAdapter() {
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

override fun getItem(i: Int): Any? {
    return null
}

override fun getItemId(i: Int): Long {
    return 0
}

override fun getView(i: Int, view: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup): View {
    var view = view
    if (view == null) {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false)
    }

    val textView = view!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

    textView.text = list[i].productType + " " + list[i].readable

    return textView

}
}
```

**Spinner item layout as "item":**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Now some changes in your existing files:**

**"ApiModel.kt":**

```
 class TypeDataResponse(
    val children: List<ProductTypeChildrenResponse>
 )

 class ProductTypeChildrenResponse(val data: ProductTypeDataResponse)

 class ProductTypeDataResponse(
    val productType: String,
    val readable: String
 )
```

**"RestAPI.kt"**

```
 class RestAPI() {

private val tigaerApi: TigaerApi

init {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://app.tigaer.id/laravel/")
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

    tigaerApi = retrofit.create(TigaerApi::class.java)
}

fun getNews(): Call<List<ProductTypeDataResponse>> {
    return tigaerApi.getTop()
}
}
```

Hence it will work for you.

Comment: your answer alone has given me hope. very thanks for it. i will try today and let you know the result. thank you!

Comment: @kakashi. How are you? And don't worry it's working. I checked and verified at my end .

Comment: it works like a charm. THANK YOU! you make my day! i will try to learn the meaning of each of your code.

Comment: Thank you soo much for such a greatful pleasure @kakashi. You also make my day after this complement. Please ask me whatever and whenever you need. my contact: ankitpatidar030@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

> is there any function to debug object/array as detail as in laravel ?

Go through this to run your app in debug mode. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

You can always use breakpoints to evaluate expressions while the app is running. Instead of logging put a breakpoint at this line.

```
 val news = response.body()
```

so when you'll receive a response from server, app will stop at this point and you can check what you are getting in response in detail.

> how to populate my json return data into spinner?

If you are getting response from server in Json format as shown in provided link, you'll have to parse the data into a list of objects(POJO).
And then you have to forward this data(maybe you'll have to iterate over list to get the required data because you have two fields in each object) into an adapter and set that adapter to your spinner. It is explained very clearly at following link.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea in this post, maybe my logic can help anyone in here

this is my JSON

```
{
"success": 1,
"dataset": [
    {
        "id": "3",
        "nama": "Rush"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "nama": "Avanza"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "nama": "Innova"
    },
    {
        "id": "14",
        "nama": "Sienta"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "nama": "Alphard"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "nama": "Calya"
    }
],
"sql_duration": 0.0013179779052734375,
"auth_duration": 1.9073486328125e-6,
"req_duration": 0.004480123519897461,
"debug_duration": []
}
```

this is my API Service

**ApiMain.kt**

```
class ApiMain : Application(){
private var BASE_URL = "your url in here"

private val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
    })
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(client)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
val services: ApiServices = retrofit.create(ApiServices::class.java)
}
```

and this is my API service

**ApiServices.kt**

```
interface ApiServices {
    @GET("yourlink")
    fun MerkKendaraan():Call<MerkKendaraan>
}
```

and this is my model

**kendaraan.kt**

```
data class MerkKendaraan(
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
var success: Int? = null,

@SerializedName("dataset")
@Expose
var dataset: List<MerkMobil>? = null,

@SerializedName("sql_duration")
@Expose
var sql_duration: String? = null,

@SerializedName("auth_duration")
@Expose
var auth_duration: String? = null,

@SerializedName("req_duration")
@Expose
var req_duration: String? = null

)

data class MerkMobil(
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("nama")
    @Expose
    var nama: String? = null
)
```

and this is my main activity

**AddKendaraan**

```
class AddKendaraan : AppCompatActivity() {

private var merk : ArrayList<MerkMobil> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_kendaraan)
    configspinnermobil()
}

private fun configspinnermobil() {
    val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerMerk)

    ApiMain().services.MerkKendaraan().enqueue(object :
        Callback<MerkKendaraan> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<MerkKendaraan>, response: Response<MerkKendaraan>) {
            //Tulis code jika response sukses
            Log.d("data api", "data masuk")
            if(response.code() == 200){
                    merk = response.body()?.dataset as ArrayList<MerkMobil>
                var data : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
                merk.forEach {
                    data.add(0,it.nama.toString())
                }
                spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this@AddKendaraan, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, data)
            }else{

            }

        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<MerkKendaraan>, t: Throwable){
            //Tulis code jika response fail
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Log.d("data api", "data tidak masuk")

        }
    })
}
```